# SQL join to join 2 tables having common columns without using join keyword

Tags: sql, oracle, join

[t2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fr08m.jpg)I'm trying to join 2 tables without using join keyword.Both tables have same kind of data but order is different. I want to display Rank,Airport info from both tables namely airports2017 and airports2010 when their ranks are different in 2 tables otherwise skip that row. How can i do this without using join keyword?

[t1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fFnML.png)

Comment: And why don't you want to use `JOIN`?

Comment: Because I want to check whether i can do this without join to understand the working of joins without using it.

Comment: Sample data and desired results would really help.

Comment: You could avoid the standard `join` keyword by using `where` clause joins (`from t1, t2 where t2.key = t1.key` etc) but I'm not sure what the learning benefit would be. Write joins using `join` syntax, there is other stuff to learn.

Comment: Sure. Thanks for the help.

Comment: As already mentioned you can use `where` instead of `join` but it does exactly the same thing (a join). It is _recommended_ to use the join syntax because defining outer joins using `where` syntax is ambiguous. So just use `join`

Comment: Define "without using join keyword". Comma is not the join keyword but it means cross join. And why don't you want to? Every query is equivalent to one expressible using product (cross join), union, minus (except), restrict (where), project (select column), rename (select as) & grouping/aggregation (plus scalar functions & for CTEs recursion). Read about relational algebra. Also, what have you tried? Please read & act on [ask] & hits googling 'stackexchange homework'. Now you are asking us to do your work.

Comment: Please read & act on [mcve]. Give a clear specification & i/o for code that works & code that doesn't. Please [use text, not images/links, for text (including code, tables & ERDs)](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/3404097). Use an image only for convenience to supplement text and/or for what cannot be given in text. And never give a diagram without a legend/key. Use edit functions to inline, not link, if you have the rep--make your post self-contained.

Comment: "display Rank,Airport info from both tables" "when their ranks are different in 2 tables otherwise skip that row." does not make sense. It is just a bunch of words that have something to do with what you actually want. Please edit your question to use enough words & sentences to be clear. Finish/fix this sentence: A row (rank, airport,  ...) is in the result when it is in airport2017 and there are no values for location, ... where row (rank, airport, location, ...) is in airport2010 ... or when it .... Or express it using set operators to talk about the sets of rows in base & result tables.

Comment: Sure. Thank you for pointing me out.

Comment: Please edit per comments. Especially re "without using join keyword" & clear specification.

Answer (score 0):

I really am not certain if this is what you are looking for, but this will find an list the differences in two tables that have columns col_a and col_b:

```
    WITH
    aset AS
        (SELECT col_a, col_b FROM table_a
         MINUS
         SELECT col_a, col_b FROM table_b),
    bset AS
        (SELECT col_a, col_b FROM table_b
         MINUS
         SELECT col_a, col_b FROM table_a)
SELECT 'A unique records' AS TYPE, a.*
  FROM aset a
UNION ALL
SELECT 'B unique records' AS TYPE, a.*
  FROM bset a
```

Comment: It is showing entries where airport names are same . It should show only those entries where rank and airport names are different.

Comment: so final output should only contain 98 entries .it should discard first 2 rows as in both tables these airports have same rank and airport names.

Answer (score 0):

While I am not sure *why* you want to do this, this query will give you what you want:

```
select airport, max(rank2017) as Rank2017, max(Rank2018) as Rank2018 from 
(
    select airport, airportrank as rank2017, 0 as rank2018 from airport2017
    union
    select airport, 0 as rank2017, airportrank as rank2018 from airport2018
) tabs
group by airport
```

If you only want ones where the rank has changed, add at the bottom:

```
having max(rank2017)<>max(Rank2018)
```

Answer (score 0):

this will work as you wanted withuot using join:

```
select a.rank,a.airport from t1 a, t2 b
where a.rank=b.rank
```

thank you.

Comment: Comma is cross join. It's not clear what the asker means by "without using join keyword". See comments. Also although the required result is not clearly described, there is no way that this calculates it--they want rows *without* a match. See the question body.